# Some build error in my Lock-on System code

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```js
public var Locked : Texture;
public var Locking : Texture;
var cam : Camera;
public var trans : Transform;

function Start() {
    trans = trasform;
}

function Update() {
    if(enemyAI.Locked > 0 ) {
    guiTexture.texture = enabled;   //build error -> cannot convert 'boolean' to 'UnityEngine.Texture'. (BCE0022)
    guiTexture.texture = Locked;
    transform.position = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(enemyAI.Locked.position);
}
    if(enemyAI.Locking > 0 ) {
    guitexture.texture = enabled;   //equal error 
    guiTexture.texture = Locking;
    transform.position = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(enemyAI.Locking.position);
}
    else
    guiTexture.texture = false;    //equal error
}
```

In enemyAI.js, if enemy get in Lock-on Range than change tag and Locked's increase each enemy. 3seconds after Locking integer = Locked. if enemy get out of Lock-on Range, Locked--

how to fix this code? When the target is within the range specified by the code I want..

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for is the `enabled` member of a [GUITExture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUITexture.html). That is a boolean which can be set.

So you would replace your

```
guiTexture.texture = enabled;
```

with

```
guiTexture.enabled = true;
```

That should do the job.

Comment: Wonderful. Glad that helped. Just make sure to always refer back to the documentation. That will help tremendously. ;)

Comment: @Bart +1 very nice, I saw ..recently you have added wonderful stuff on Unity3D, we appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Thanks @RDC. That's very kind of you.

Comment: @Bart yeah!! by the way.. congrats for 10k as we believe it will give you more power on SO tools. so you can make better.